# Sorting a photoset with the Flickr API

Tags: flickr

Is there a simple way to sort a photset in reverse chronological order (i.e. "Arrange by date taken (newest first)" using the Flickr API rather than the edit interface?

Comment: fwiw, in 2016, the [docs](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getList.html) say: Photosets are returned in the user's specified order, which may not mean the newest set is first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the `date_taken` field when you call [getPhotos](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html), and then sort the results yourself...

Comment: ...then use the sorted ids in [flickr.photosets.reorderPhotos](https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.reorderPhotos.html)